# Piecemeal Dynamic SQL? How to take search criteria as column value strings and make them where clause code?

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to build a function or sample code that is using column string data as the predicate logic for my `where` clause.  Examples of strings in the established table's columns are:

```
'1=1', '1=2', 'DEPT_DESC = Sales', 'RPM_CODE IN('MS-123','MS-124','MS-126')'
```

I've been investigating ways you can build-out Dynamic SQL and inject this column data into part of a greater Dynamic SQL execution but I'm coming up short.  This seems like a very easy thing my co-workers were able to do in Oracle and I am hitting a frustrating roadblock here on SQL's end.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the my code example:
`'SELECT * FROM ALL_TRANS WHERE ____'` (The blank is where I need to inject the string into the clause.)

Comment: If you add your current dynamic SQL code to your question, it might help you get an answer faster.

Comment: Not sure it helped, but I provided a bit more context.

Comment: Is there a procedural language involved?  VBA? C#? C/C+ ?  It is hard to propose a solution without knowing more.  Also, in the '1=1' is it used to select all rows in the table?  And what use is '1=2'?  And what column would it apply to?  Is DEPT_DESC the sql column name?  Will RPM_CODE always be a string of OR-s? or may there be parens with OR/NOT/AND??

Comment: I'm translating Oracle SQL code into T-SQL.  This will a secondary filter after a larger categorical one.  1=1 will be all rows should satisfy the criteria and 1=2 will mean no rows should satisfy the criteria.  There will be ORs, and ANDs.

Comment: I've written queries that included _snippets_ which were replaced on-the-fly before execution, e.g. `select * from Projects where ProjectOwnerId = «CurrentUserId»;`. The application substitutes the appropriate value(s). You could do something similar, e.g. `select A, B, C from MyTable «WhereClause» order by DueDate desc;`. Either replace "«WhereClause»" with "where " and a condition or remove it before execution. Funny that you mention _inject_. If the source of the substitute text isn't absolutely trustworthy then you are allowing _evil_ [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, creating dynamic SQL where the COLUMN names may change,
involves having a SQL_Model that has 1 or more keywords changed
to result in a SQL_toExec that is given to the instance.

```
The SQL_Model that is easily extensible might be
   SQL_Model = 'SELECT * FROM ALL_TRANS WHEREWXYZ'
Then move SQL_toExec = SQL_Model
And thru  SQL_toExec = Replace(SQL_toExec, 'WXYZ', ', DEPT_DESC = SalesWXYZ') 
to get   'SELECT * FROM ALL_TRANS WHERE, DEPT_DESC = SalesWXYZ'
And thru  SQL_toExec = Replace(SQL_toExec, 'WXYZ', ', RPM_CODE IN(''MS-123'',''MS-124'')WXYZ') 
 to get  'SELECT * FROM ALL_TRANS WHERE, DEPT_DESC = Sales, RPM_CODE IN(''MS-123'',''MS-124'')WXYZ'

The SQL_toExec keeps getting longer, with more columns added
And then two final replaces to clean things up
    SQL_toExec = Replace(SQL_toExec, 'WHERE,', 'WHERE ')   'remove the initial comma
    SQL_toExec = Replace(SQL_toExec, 'WXYZ', '')           ' remove the trailing WXYZ
```

And you are ready to go.